# Why can't I override this property of a Java class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I wrote a small subclass of `java.time.Clock` in Kotlin.

This version of it works:

```
class TestClock(
    var instant: Instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(0),
    zone: ZoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC")
) : Clock() {
    private val zone = zone

    override fun getZone(): ZoneId = zone

    override fun withZone(zone: ZoneId): Clock =
        if (zone == this.zone) this else TestClock(instant, zone)

    override fun instant(): Instant = instant
}
```

but if I try to remove the redundancy around the `zone` property, like this:

```
class TestClock(
    var instant: Instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(0),
    override val zone: ZoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC")
) : Clock() {
    override fun withZone(zone: ZoneId): Clock =
        if (zone == this.zone) this else TestClock(instant, zone)

    override fun instant(): Instant = instant
}
```

...I get two seemingly contradictory error messages:

> Error:(7, 1) Kotlin: Class 'TestClock' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun getZone(): ZoneId! defined in java.time.Clock
>   Error:(9, 5) Kotlin: 'zone' overrides nothing

Doesn't `override val zone` override the `getZone(): ZoneId!` defined in java.time.Clock'?

Comment: seems to be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653